# arrange numbers or alphabets in following matrix form

Tags: matrix

```
for n = 3:

1 3 6
2 5 8
4 7 9  

this is diffrent from diagonal printing.
```

If we are given n then we have to print in 2d matrix from upto n.

Comment: Language? What have you tried?

Comment: Any language, I just want solution not exact code. I am not able to start yet.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int[][] zigzag(final int size)
 {
   int[][] data = new int[size][size];
    int i = 1;
     int j = 1;
     for (int element = 0; element < size * size; element++)
{
data[i - 1][j - 1] = element;
if ((i + j) % 2 == 0)
{
// Even stripes
if (j < size)
j++;
else
i+= 2;
if (i > 1)
i--;
}
else
{
 // Odd stripes
 if (i < size)
 i++;
 else
 j+= 2;
 if (j > 1)
 j--;
 }
 }
  return data;
  }
```